# Efficient way of adding row with difference from specific group in data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data table:

```
require(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(ind = 1:8, cat = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D"), counts = (10:3))

    ind cat counts
1:   1   A     10
2:   2   A      9
3:   3   A      8
4:   4   B      7
5:   5   B      6
6:   6   C      5
7:   7   C      4
8:   8   D      3
```

What I would like to achieve is to add a row for each cat which in the counts has the difference between the sum(counts) of the cat and the sum(counts) of cat A. For these rows the ind should be 0.
Essentially I would like to rbind the following information:

```
added_info <- cbind(ind =0, dt1[, .(counts = dt1[cat == "A", sum(counts)] - sum(counts)), by = cat])

> added_info
   ind cat counts
1:   0   A      0
2:   0   B     14
3:   0   C     18
4:   0   D     24
```

And the end result would be:

```
dt1 <- rbind(dt1, added_info)[order(cat)]

> dt1
    ind cat counts
 1:   1   A     10
 2:   2   A      9
 3:   3   A      8
 4:   0   A      0
 5:   4   B      7
 6:   5   B      6
 7:   0   B     14
 8:   6   C      5
 9:   7   C      4
10:   0   C     18
11:   8   D      3
12:   0   D     24
```

My question is if there is a better (shorter) way of achieving this using datatable (perhaps by using .I or .N ??)

Comment: If you store the sum of cat A's counts in `x` you could do it in one step using `rbind(dt1, dt1[, .(ind = 0, counts = x - sum(counts)), by = cat], use.names =TRUE)` but I don't think this make a big difference

Comment: Maybe `dt1[,c:=sum(counts[cat=="A"])][,.(ind=c(ind,0), counts=c(counts,c[.N]-counts[.N])),cat][]`?

Comment: @docendodiscimus  yes you are right there is no significant difference. @lukeA this is not exactly what I want but by changing it a bit to `dt1[,c:=sum(counts[cat=="A"])][,.(ind=c(ind,0), counts=c(counts,c[.N]-sum(counts))),cat][]` this gives me the result I was expecting

Comment: @lukeA would you like to write it as an answer?

Comment: @User2321 sure - just did so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do

```
require(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(ind = 1:8, cat = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D"), counts = (10:3))
dt1[,c:=sum(counts[cat=="A"])][,.(ind=c(ind,0), counts=c(counts,c[.N]-sum(counts))),cat][]
#     cat ind counts
#  1:   A   1     10
#  2:   A   2      9
#  3:   A   3      8
#  4:   A   0      0
#  5:   B   4      7
#  6:   B   5      6
#  7:   B   0     14
#  8:   C   6      5
#  9:   C   7      4
# 10:   C   0     18
# 11:   D   8      3
# 12:   D   0     24
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be a solution within one data.table call:

```
dt1[, rbind(.SD, 
            data.table(ind = 0, 
                       counts = dt1[cat == 'A', sum(counts)] - sum(.SD$counts))), 
    by = cat]
```

Out:

```
   cat ind counts
 1:   A   1     10
 2:   A   2      9
 3:   A   3      8
 4:   A   0      0
 5:   B   4      7
 6:   B   5      6
 7:   B   0     14
 8:   C   6      5
 9:   C   7      4
10:   C   0     18
11:   D   8      3
12:   D   0     24
```

Comment: Don't you think `rbind`ing and calling `data.table()` by group is less efficient than just computing a summary and rbinding that to dt1 once? Plus, you have to compute the A-sum in each group, right? (I haven't tested it, it's just a guess)

Comment: True @docendodiscimus it is about 2.5 time less efficient on my laptop (and not calculating A-sum within each group). But I 'm only providing an alternative just for expanding on the ways you can do this. Having a small data set would not affect this dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

You said efficient, so... This has two by's; the unique is likely vectorized and the data.table by for sum should compile to a c for loop.

```
> dt1[, .SD
      ][, ca := sum(.SD[cat == 'A', counts])
      ][, cc := sum(counts), cat
      ][, cd := ca - cc
      ][, rbind(.SD, unique(.SD, by=c('cat'))[, `:=`(ind=0)])
      ][ind == 0, counts := cd
      ][, .(cat, ind, counts)
      ][order(cat, ind)
      ]

    cat ind counts
 1:   A   0      0
 2:   A   1     10
 3:   A   2      9
 4:   A   3      8
 5:   B   0     14
 6:   B   4      7
 7:   B   5      6
 8:   C   0     18
 9:   C   6      5
10:   C   7      4
11:   D   0     24
12:   D   8      3
>
```